# Week To Date Based Off Current Date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am looking for an expression that will allow to me find the date of Monday of the week of my Date Field, to be used in a filter for a tablix.

Example, my date field today is 22/01/2019. I would like an expression that will return 21/01/2019. If the date was 26/01/2019, it should still return 21/01/2019.

For next week 31/01/2019 would return 28/01/2019.

Week starting Monday going to Sunday.

If its also possible for a similiar expression but to find the beginning of the month as well?

Is that possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the date of last Monday that occurred you can use something like

```
=Today.AddDays(1-WeekDay(Today(),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday))
```

and for the first of the month its just

```
=DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1)
```

Both the above are based on the today() function, if you need them based on a date parameter, then the expression is a little different but your question stated "today".

Answer (score 0):

monday of the week use the following expression:

DateAdd("d",DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay,Fields!myDatefield.Value,0,0)+1,Fields!myDatefield.Value)

first day of the month use the following expression:

=DateAdd("d",-(Day(Fields!myDatefield.Value)-1), Fields!myDatefield.Value)